# package installed but cannot import it

Tags: python, importerror

I have successfully installed the bitarray package, because I can find it after the command: pip list.

But when I try to import it I get :

```
>>> from bitarray import bitarray

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from bitarray import bitarray
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitarray'
```

What can I try to solve it ?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 .

Comment: Did you install it for the correct python version?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I guess yes... I wrote the command pip install bitarray in the terminal

Comment: You can install package as `python3 -m pip install bitarray`. May be when you did `pip install bitarray`, it install your package for python2.

Comment: check with `pip show bitarray` which version you installed and wheter it matches your python-version (use `-V` switch to check python-version)

Comment: YOU BOTH WERE RIGHT !! JAY PATEL YOU SOLVED IT THANK YOU !!

Comment: wuerfelfreak THANK YOU FOR THE INFO. NEXT TIME I'LL CHECK VERSION WITH YOUR COMMANDS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install package as `python3 -m pip install bitarray`. May be when you did `pip install bitarray`, it install your package for `python2`.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with two python versions. If you just ran `pip install x` it installed it into python 2.7. You're probably using python3, so you wanna install with `pip3 install x`

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you are running correct pip, try running "pip -V" or "pip --version", it gives you which version of python it refers to. In terminal it looks something like this [pip version check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5uVF.png)
Its also possible that you might have pip for say python 2.7, pip3 for python 3.6, and pip3.7 for python 3.7, if you have multiple versions of python installed.
For simplicity you can set the most frequently used pip version as pip by setting an alias in ~/.bashrc. This is done by adding the following line in bashrc:

alias pip=pip3.6.

After this you can try and install the packages and import it swiftly.